# Trying to install graphics.tar.gz with pip and it gives an error

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, graphics

So I put the package at /Scripts open command window at that window, and type pip install graphics.py-5.0.1.tar.gz , which it then returns an error:

> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tkinter (from
>   graphics .py==5.0.1) (from versions: ) No matching distribution found
>   for tkinter (from graphics.py==5.0.1)

What do I do? I'm on Windows 8.1, using Python 3.6